# Determine if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{n}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{n}}$ converges or not using comparison test?

I tried the ratio test, and I couldn't use it because $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: It diverges by the divergence test

Comment: Cant you use the limit comparison test

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: It's an exercise I couldnt solve

Comment: I (and carmichael) told you how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that if $\sum_{n}a_n$ is a convergent series then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

In this case, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{2^n+1}=1\neq 0$, the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$2^n \ge 1$,
$1+2^n
\le 2\cdot 2^n$,
so
$\frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{n}}
\ge \frac12$.

Therefore
$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{n}}
\ge \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac12
=\frac{m}{2}
$,
so the sum diverges
as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: For a constructive approach (+1).  Judging by the votes, applying the divergence test was viewed as quite remarkable.

Comment: I think that it being submitted an hour earlier made the difference.